# ActiveDirectory with Range not changing results using DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, active-directory

So I'm basically trying to enumerate results from AD, and for some reason I'm unable to pull down new results, meaning it keeps continuously pulling the first 1500 results even though I tell it I want an additional range.

Can someone point out where I'm making the mistake? The code never breaks out of the loop but more importantly it pulls users 1-1500 even when I say I want users 1500-3000.

```
uint rangeStep = 1500;   
uint rangeLow = 0;   
uint rangeHigh = rangeLow + (rangeStep - 1);   
bool lastQuery = false;   
bool quitLoop = false;   

do   
{                       
    string attributeWithRange;   
    if (!lastQuery)   
    {   
        attributeWithRange = String.Format("member;Range={0}-{1}", rangeLow, rangeHigh);   
    }   
    else   
    {   
        attributeWithRange = String.Format("member;Range={0}-*", rangeLow);   
    }   
    DirectoryEntry dEntryhighlevel = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=C,OU=x,DC=h,DC=nt");   
    DirectorySearcher dSeacher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntryhighlevel,"(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=Users,OU=t,OU=s,OU=x,DC=h,DC=nt))",new string[] {attributeWithRange});   
    dSeacher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");   
    dSeacher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");   
    dSeacher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");   
    dSeacher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");   
    dSeacher.PageSize = 1500;   
    SearchResultCollection resultCollection = resultCollection = dSeacher.FindAll();   
    dSeacher.Dispose();   

    foreach (SearchResult userResults in resultCollection)   
    {   

        string Last_Name = userResults.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();   
        string First_Name = userResults.Properties["givenname"][0].ToString();   
        string userName = userResults.Properties["samAccountName"][0].ToString();   
        string Email_Address = userResults.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();   
        OriginalList.Add(Last_Name + "|" + First_Name + "|" + userName + "|" + Email_Address);   
    }   
    if(resultCollection.Count == 1500)   
    {   
        lastQuery = true;   
        rangeLow = rangeHigh + 1;   
        rangeHigh = rangeLow + (rangeStep - 1);   
    }   
    else   
    {   
        quitLoop = true;   
    }   

}   
while (!quitLoop);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up two concepts which is what is causing you trouble. This is a FAQ on the SO forums so I probably should blog on this to try and clear things up.

Let me first just explain the concepts, then correct the code once the concepts are out there.

Concept one is fetching large collections of objects. When you fetch a lot of objects, you need to ask for them in batches. **This is typically called *paging* through the results**. When you do this you'll get back a paging cookie and can pass back the paged control in subsequent searches to keep getting a "page worth" of results with each pass.

The second concept is fetching large numbers of values from a single attribute. The simple example of this is reading the member attribute from a group (ex: doing a base search for that group). **This is called *ranged retrieval***. In this search mode you are doing a base search against that object for the large attribute (like member) and asking for "ranges" of values with each passing search.

The code above confuses these concepts. You are doing member range logic like you are doing range retrieval but you are in fact doing a search that is constructed to return a large # of objects like a paged search. This is why you are getting the same results over and over.

To fix this you need to first pick an approach. :) **I recommend range retrieval against the group object** and asking for the large member attribute in ranges. This will get you all of the members in the group.
If you go down this path, you'll notice you can't ask for attributes for these values. The only value you get is the list of members, and you can then do searches for them. **If you opt to stay with paged searches like you have above**, then you end up switching to paged searches.

If you opt to stick with paged searches, then you'll need to:

- Get rid of the Range logic, and all mentions of 1500
- Set a page size of something like 1000
- Instead of ranging, look up how to do paged searches (using the page search control) using your API

**If you pick ranging**, you'll switch from a **memberOf** search like this to a search of the form:

- scope: base
- filter: (objectclass=*)
- base DN: OU=C,OU=x,DC=h,DC=nt
- Attributes: member;Range=0-*...

Then you will increment the 0 up as you fetch ranges of values (i.e. do this search over and over again for each subsequent range of values, changing only the 0 to subsequent integers)

Other points you'll notice in my logic:

- I don't set page size...you're not doing a paged search, so it doesn't matter.
- I dont' ever hard code the value 1500 here. It doesn't matter. Ther eis no value in knowing or even computing this. The point is that you asked for 0-* (ie all), you got back 1500, so then you say 1500-*, then 3000-*, and so on. You don't need to knwo the range size, only what you have been given so far.

I hope this fully answers it...

**Here is a code snip of doing a paged search**, per my comment below (this is what you would need to do using the **System.DirectoryServices.Protocols** namespace classes, going down the logical path you started above (paged searches, not ranged retrieval)):

```
        string searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=Users,OU=t,OU=s,OU=x,DC=h,DC=nt))";
        string baseDN = "OU=C,OU=x,DC=h,DC=nt";
        var scope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        var attributeList = new string[] { "givenname", "sn", "samAccountName", "mail" };
        PageResultRequestControl pageSearchControl = new PageResultRequestControl(1000);
        do
        {
            SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest(baseDN, searchFilter, scope, attributeList);
            sr.Controls.Add(pageSearchControl);

            var directoryResponse = ldapConnection.SendRequest(sr);
            if (directoryResponse.ResultCode != ResultCode.Success)
            {
                // Handle error
            }

            var searchResponse = (SearchResponse)directoryResponse;

            pageSearchControl = null; // Reset!
            foreach (var control in searchResponse.Controls)
            {
                if (control is PageResultResponseControl)
                {
                    var prrc = (PageResultResponseControl)control;
                    if (prrc.Cookie.Length > 0)
                    {
                        pageSearchControl = new PageResultRequestControl(prrc.Cookie);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var entry in searchResponse.Entries)
            {
                // Handle the search result entry
            }
        } while (pageSearchControl != null);
```

Comment: Eric, unfortunately that only works if the results are below 1500, in this case it's not.  So even setting the page sizes will not return all.  Default page size is 1000, you have to override it.   I'll give the filter a shot.  I really seriously think with your answer you tried to hard..  The ranging code portion worked fine, as I said i'll try the filter

Comment: Eric, i'm also not really confusing anything, thats MSDN example

Comment: Whats the syntax to add range to the filter?  Because there doesn't appear to be any examples...

Comment: this is my filter "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=Users,OU=t,OU=s,OU=x,DC=h,DC=nt)(member;range=0-1499))"

Comment: If you cite the MSDN article I'm happy to follow up with the author and have it corrected.
It is confusing them. Trust me, I worked on this stuff @ MSFT. :) I'll post an updated code snip in a moment that does it correctly in the original post.

Comment: BTW, you should find that you get the exact same results w/o the ranging logic, which would confirm my assertion. if it changes, then there is something being misstated...there is no overlap between ranged retrieval and paged searches, which is what the code sample above is doing.

Comment: If that fails, perhaps just logically describe what you are trying to do and I can give you a code sample...that way I'm not reverse engineering what you are trying to do from the code above?
Thx.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is caused by creating new object of directory searcher in loop. Each time there will be new object that will take first 1500 records. Create instance of searher out of the loop and use same instance for all queries.